# Deleting question until references found

Tags: discussion, deletion

I [have asked this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32258/bottle-scarred-battle-scared-veteran) and it lacks references to notability. We had a chat with @Jamiec and I promised to update my question. Problem is I have heard this story it in one of audible lectures told by professor and now having hard time finding which one it is (since there is no way to search in audio). I am now re-listening to series of lectures (that I think story came from) but it takes time.

**Would it be more appropriate to delete question until I have found source of the story and once found to edit and undelete it? Or should I just leave it until then?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to leave it closed and undeleted, because then anyone can see and edit it, if they have a notable source.